# Can the degree of $k$-nilpotence of a simple simply connected compact Lie group be in $(0,1)$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, harmonic-analysis, haar-measure, compactness

Let $G$ be a simple (i.e. *every proper normal subgroup is discrete*) simply connected compact Lie group. Define **the degree of $k$-nilpotence** of $G$ to be the Haar measure of the set
$$\{(x_1,\dotsc,x_{k+1}): [x_1,\dotsc,x_{k+1}]=1\}.$$
($[x,y]=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$ and $[x_1,\dotsc,x_{k+1}]:=[[x_1,\dotsc,x_k],x_{k+1}]$.)
The following question is raised in [Martino, Tointon, Valiunas, and Ventura - Probabilistic nilpotence in infinite groups](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11856-021-2168-3):

> Does a compact group with positive degree of $k$-nilpotence have an
> open $k$-step nilpotent subgroup?

Is it easy to answer this question when $G$ is a simple simply connected compact Lie group?

Comment: This is a proper Zariski-closed subset (whenever $G$ is a nontrivial semisimple connected compact group). So it has Haar masure zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a positive answer of the question for arbitrary compact Lie groups. For a group $G$, denote $W_k(G)=\{x\in G^k:[x_1,\dots,x_k]=1\}$.

> Let $G$ be a compact Lie group. Then $W_k(G)$ has nonzero Haar measure for some $k\ge 1$ if and only if $G^0$ is a torus.

One direction is obvious: if $G^0$ is a torus, then $(G^0)^k\subset W_k^G$ has positive measure (for every $k\ge 2$).

Conversely, we assume $W_k$ has nonzero Haar measure. If $k=1$, it follows that $G$ is finite and we are done. Assuming otherwise, $k\ge 2$.

The subset $W_k(G)\subset G^k$ is Zariski-closed. Since it has nonzero Haar measure, it therefore contains $\prod_{i=1}^k C_i$ for cosets $C_i$ of $G^0$. [If $G$ is connected, this is $G^k$, so $G$ is nilpotent, hence is a torus and the proof is finished.]

I assume the conventions $[x,y]=xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ and that the iterated commutator is defined by $[x]=x$ and $[x_1,\dots,x_k]=[x_1,[x_2,\dots,x_k]]$ for $k\ge 2$. Also, by $[X_1,\dots,X_k]$ I mean the set $\{[x_1,\dots,x_k]:x_i\in X_i\}$ (rather than the group it generates).

Now assume that $G^0$ is semisimple and nontrivial. I need an inductive argument.  Namely, to reach a contradiction, choose $k\ge 2$ minimal for the property that there are cosets $C_1,\dots,C_k$ of $G^0$ such that $[C_1,\dots,C_k]$ is a singleton, say $w$. Necessarily $k\ge 2$.

Define $Y=\{[x_2,\dots,x_k]:x_i\in C_i,\forall i\ge 2\}$. Then $[x,y]=w$ for all $x\in C_1$ and $y\in Y$. Then for all $s\in G^0$, $x\in C_1,y\in Y$, we have $$w=[x,y]=[xs,y]=x[s,y]x^{-1}[x,y]= x[s,y]x^{-1}w,$$
and hence $[s,y]=1$. Thus, $Y$ is contained in the centralizer of $G^0$. Since $G^0$ is semisimple, its centralizer is finite. Hence $Y=[C_2,\dots,C_k]$ is finite, hence a singleton by connectedness. This contradicts the minimality of $k$.

Now the result is proved when $G^0$ is semisimple (i.e., when $G^0$ is semisimple, if $W_k(G)$ has nonempty interior implies $G^0=1$). In general, let $Z$ be the center of $G^0$. If $W_k(G)$ has nonempty interior, since the projection $G\to G/Z$ is open and so is $G^k\to (G/Z)^k$, the subset $W_k(G/Z)$ (which contains the projection of $W_k(G)$) has nonempty interior. So, by the semisimple case $(G/Z)^0$ is trivial. That is, $Z=G^0$.

[Edit: I fixed my previous argument]

Comment: @MeisamSoleimaniMalekan Zariski-closed subsets appear in many introductory textbooks in algebraic geometry. I'm using that every compact Lie group appears as Zariski-closed subgroup in $M_n(\mathbf{R})$ for some $n$; Zariski-closed meaning: set of zero of some set of polynomials. For the Haar measure fact, it's standard but I'm not sure of a reference. The intuition is that unless it contains a component, it is of smaller dimension and, being regular enough, has measure zero.  (More precisely, is a finite union of smooth locally closed subvarieties...)

Comment: Did you read questions 2 and 3 in my previous comment? I think your argument works just  for semisimple connected compact Lie groups.

Comment: @MeisamSoleimaniMalekan (2) Yes. (3) No, I assume that the Haar measure assumption holds in $G$, then I deduce it also holds in $G/Z$. My argument is quite precise. The argument that if $W_k(G)$ has nonzero Haar measure then it has nonempty interior was explained earlier, it doesn't use semisimplicity.

Comment: Great! An irrelevant question: Let $H$ be a closed subgroup of a compact Lie group $G$. Is the following set Zariski-closed in $H$, $\{(h_1,\dotsc,h_n): [g_1h_1,\dotsc,g_nh_n]=1\}$ for $g_i$ in $G$?

Comment: @MeisamSoleimaniMalekan Yes, because it's the inverse image of a singleton by a regular map.

Comment: Would you mind editing in "Yes, a compact group with positive degree of $k$-nilpotence have an open $k$-step nilpotent subgroup" (in place of "a positive answer of the question")?  Even though the rest of the question makes it clear, I always find myself tripping over answers that start like that.

Comment: @YCor by the openness of $G^0$, if it is semisimple and $W_k$ has positive Haar measure, then $G$ should be finite, am I right?

Comment: @MeisamSoleimaniMalekan Yes, this appears in the proof when dealing with the case when $G^0$ is semisimple.