# Only Zariski-closed subsets of compact Lie groups with nonempty interior have nonzero measure

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, lie-groups, real-algebraic-geometry, haar-measure

In [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/404459/can-the-degree-of-k-nilpotence-of-a-simple-simply-connected-compact-lie-group/404514#404514), the following fact was used by the respondent

> A Zariski-closed subset of a compact Lie group $G$ with nonzero Haar
> measure contains a coset of $G^0$, the connected component of
> $G$ containing the identity of the group.

Can anyone provide a reference for this statement?

Comment: The Haar measure is zero on any submanifold of positive codimension, as it is given (on a finite covering space) by integrating a differential form of top degree. But a Lie subgroup of equal dimension contains an open set, so translating that open set contains the identity component.

Comment: Please edit the title of your question so that it conveys the problem that you're asking about. The purpose of the question title is to help people decide whether to open and read your question.

Comment: @JoeSilverman thanks for the comment, I did.

Comment: To complete Ben McKay's comment, a Zariski-closed subset can be singular, but still is a finite union of Zariski-locally-closed subsets (and hence a countable union of closed smooth submanifolds with boundary).